# udp headers in c to communicate with audio gear

Tags: c, raspberry-pi

I recently stumbled across a document for a processor that I use at work that outlines the udp protocols that they use.  My end goal would be to build a little box with some simple controls powered by a raspberry pi zero that communicates with the processor(s) via udp.

To get started I've assumed that I would need to program raw packets based on the information that I found in the document.  This is a small excerpt from the document:

> In order to implement external control the controlling application
>   must transmit and receive properly formed UDP packets to and from a
>   network of devices.

There is also a table (attached as a picture) outlining specifics for the structure of the header.

I've done a little bit of googling and experimenting with raw udp coding for linux.  Does anyone have a good example of how to form the header in the way that the document outlines?

The processor is a Lake LM44 [documentation link](https://kb.musictribe.com/musickb/servlet/fileField?retURL=%2Fmusickb%2Fapex%2Fview%3Fid%3DkA028000000NBkiCAG%26lg%3Den_US%26name%3D&entityId=ka00I000000gRVJQA2&field=Attachment__Body__s)

Comment: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.* https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: You didn't even specify what "processor" that is nor did you include the document.

Comment: @KamilCuk edits have been made to the OP

Answer (score 0):

The best way to learn to code IP (TCP & UDP) in C/C++ is to read beej's guide to networking, https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/